# How to remove "middle-process" data from a table?

Tags: ms-access

I have this machine where you can process a material over and over until it becomes a product.

The `INPUT` of the machine looks like this:

```
DateI         Code     #Orderofday
-----------------------------
25/02/2019    A0001    1
25/02/2019    B0001    2   
27/02/2019    B0002    1
28/02/2019    A0002    1
01/02/2019    B0004    1
01/02/2019    B0003    2
01/02/2019    B0005    3
```

And the `OUTPUT` looks like this:

```
DateI         Code     #Orderofday
-----------------------------
25/02/2019    B0001    1
25/02/2019    B0002    2
27/02/2019    B0003    1
28/02/2019    B0004    1
01/02/2019    B0005    1
01/02/2019    WINSOR   2
01/02/2019    APRSHA   3
```

As you can see from the tables, `A0001` in the `INPUT` is processed to become `B0001` in the `OUTPUT`. And then `B0001` becomes the `INPUT` and get processed again to become `B0002` etc.

The starting material has a `Code` column that always begins with a letter "A" followed by 4 numbers, the middle-process always begins with "B" followed by 4 numbers, and the final product are other combination of letters. There is no fixed amount of middle-processes a material has to go through to become a product.

I want to get rid of the middle-process (the `Code` that starts with "B") to make the final result to look like this:

```
matco     product
-----------------
A0001     APRSHA
A0002     WINSOR
```

Is there anyway to do this? Much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried delete query?

Comment: Yes but it only deletes the `code` that starts with B. I can't get a table that can make me know that `APRSHA` comes from `A0001`.

Comment: Then you should save the starting code throughout the process so it can be saved with the 'final' output record. Otherwise, what rules dictate that A0001 belongs with APRSHA? Bad schema causes GIGO - garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: If you can change the tables I would add a finished product column and set it when the product is finished.  then just make a query to sort by finished product.  otherwise create a query to filter based on the code.  something like" SELECT Code WHERE not Code LIKE "[A-B][0-9]*" see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-query-criteria-3197228c-8684-4552-ac03-aba746fb29d8 or https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931